# Spark, Cassandra and Kafka (SMACK) SaaS or PaaS providers

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We are in the process of evaluating SaaS and PaaS providers for SMACK technology stack.

We want to host the nodes on AWS.

So far, we have found following alternatives:

- DCOS (https://dcos.io/)
- Instaclustr (https://www.instaclustr.com/)
- AWS ec2 - we would have to manually do all the deployment and administration
- Datastax (it has only Cassandra, we would have to deploy Spark and Kafka. Accoring to documentation, in Datastax Analytics it is quite easy to deploy Spark). Problem also is that in last version of Datastax Enterprise version of Spark is not 1.6 (I think it is 1.4)

Are there any possible alternatives to this?

How long "would it take us" (beginner users) to deploy option number 3 (AWS ec2), as well as how much administration time it is necessary after that? How easy is the scaling after that?

Of course, I do not expect concrete numbers and figures, just general opinions and advices from those of you who have undertaken the same process.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until [MESOS-1554 (RESOLVED)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1554) is fixed I don't recommend running c* or DSE on mesos for performance reasons.

> Accoring to documentation, in Datastax Analytics it is quite easy to
>   deploy Spark).

DSE actually ships with spark, no integration necessary.

> Problem also is that in last version of Datastax
>   Enterprise version of Spark is not 1.6 (I think it is 1.4)

DSE 5.0 will ship with spark 1.6.x and it will be GA quite soon.

> How long "would it take us" (beginner users) to deploy option number 3
>   (AWS ec2), as well as how much administration time it is necessary
>   after that? How easy is the scaling after that?

This is not an easy question to answer objectively. Take the Opps course for free on datastax academy and determine for yourself if you're equipped to do the deployment https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds210-operations-and-performance-tuning

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which cluster manger DSE uses? When is the expected issue date of DSE 5.0? Are there any Kafka deployment instructions?

Comment: Standalone+, DSE has a zookeeperless HA spark master that's implemented using paxos. No set date I can share yet but stay posted for an announcement. The kafka / dse integration is quite straight forward. Here's an example https://github.com/retroryan/spark_streaming_aggregation

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to look at this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482585/datastaxenteprise-node-vs-instance-correct-ami-image-why-do-i-need-storage

We are seriously interested in Datastax but without answers to those questions, I can not assure my supervisors Datastax is the right choice.

Thank you

Comment: You should reach out to sales@datastax to get support from a solution engineer. Anyway I'll take a look.