# DatastaxEnteprise: node vs instance, correct AMI image, why do I need storage

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

Currently, we are evaluating datastax enteprise as our provider of Cassandra and Spark.We consider deploying Datastax cluster on AWS.

I have following questions:

1) In step 1 of *Datastax on EC2* installation manual, I need to choose correct AMI Image: Currently there are 7 of them. Which is the correct one:
(DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.5.1-pv, DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.6.3-1204-pv, DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.6.3-1404-pv....)

2) The moment we launch the cluster, do we pay only for aws instances or also Datastax Enterprise licensing fee? I know there is a 30 days enterprise free trial, but nowhere in the installation process I saw a step where we can ask for the free trial? Is there some online calculator that we can use to calculate the cost of a cluster on a monthy basis (based on the instance types we create)

3) In the step 3 of the installation process *Configure Instance Details*, I am confused with terms *instance* and *nodes*. What is the difference between them? What happens if I choose:

a) 1 instance, --totalnodes 3 (in the *user data*)

b) 3 instance, --tatalnodes 3

c) 1 instance, --totalnodes 0 --analyticsnodes 3

d) 3 instance, --totalnodes 0 --analyticsnodes 3

4) We are interested in the use case where each of our 3 cassandra nodes has Spark. Is the proper user data configuration: 
*--totalnodes 0 --analyticsnodes 3*
Are then we going to have 0 nodes with only cassandra, and 3 nodes that have Cassandra and Spark? What is the *Number of instances* we should specify then?

5) In step 4 of installation process *Add Storage*, we are asked to add storage to the instance. But why do we need this storage? When choosing instance type, for example *m3.large*, I already know that my instance has 32GB of SSD storage, what is this then?

Thank you for your answers. If there is some email list to which I can send these questions, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whichever AMI has the highest version number and the virtualization type you prefer (-pv or -hvm): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html

You only pay for EC2 usage. DSE is free for testing and development. You do not need to request a trial license. If you want a production license or if you want to become a startup member, contact DataStax.

The AMI will install one "DSE node" per "EC2 instance". So if you want a six node cluster you need to specify 6 instances. To use your examples:

a) 1 instance, --totalnodes 3 (in the user data)

- This won't work

b) 3 instance, --tatalnodes 3

This will give you a three node Cassandra cluster (running on three instances). You have not specified search or analytics nodes so by default you will just get Cassandra nodes.

c) 1 instance, --totalnodes 0 --analyticsnodes 3

Won't work. Total nodes should equal number of instances and number of analytics nodes can't be greater than total nodes.

d) 3 instance, --totalnodes 0 --analyticsnodes 3

Won't work. Number of analytics nodes can't be greater than number of total nodes.

If you want a three-node cluster and you want all of them running both Cassandra and Spark use this:

3 instances, --totalnodes 3 --analyticsnodes 3

Adding storage is optional. And only possible with certain instance types. You should notice with m3.large that there is a default config and you can't actually make any changes to it.

Hope this helps!